# How to buy a free registered gmail of someone?

Tags: gmail

I would like to buy/use a gmail account that was freely registered by someone that I don't know. I can not reach him via email for any negotiation. It seems that he is not using this email. Google search shows no information on it. Just a G+ is seen.

I would like to ask that, does google has any policy permitting me to check the availability of this gmail and reuse or buy this account to use it?
How can I contact gmail admin staffs?
Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I agree with you.
I found many question tagged gmail and thought that stackoverflow is now extended to gmail too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very unlikely to work out for you. The person who holds the account is your only hope because buying and selling of accounts is against Google's terms of service, it's very unlikely they will help you.

From [Google Terms of Service](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/):

> You may not copy, modify, distribute, sell, or lease any part of our Services or included software, nor may you reverse engineer or attempt to extract the source code of that software, unless laws prohibit those restrictions or you have our written permission.

**Alternate solution:** Since you are willing to pay money, get your own custom domain and register it with Gmail. It will look more professional and leave the control of the account in your hands.

Here's [a guide](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/set-up-gmail-for-your-own-domain/) to setting up your own domain with Gmail.

Comment: Yes. I mean that if there is a way similar to the registration of a domain (website), that the buyer must pay a fee yearly to owe it. I would like to buy the stated gmail from google, not the person using it freely. How can I let google know that the gmail is not being used and should be used by other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no

Long answer: Google account usernames are not recycled for security purposes. One situation is that the original user subscribed to a private blog using the email, then the new user would also gain access to the private blog posts.

Though they do reserve the right to delete your data and deactivate your account if it is inactive for sometime (I believe 9 months), but they don't always do it. Even if they did, the username would still not be given out again.